# Change svg colour with set interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a project and I want to change the SVG color with time interval...

```
var bulbColors = [
        '#FFFFFF',
        '#27ae60',
        '#16a085',
        '#f39c12',
        '#e74c3c',
        '#9b59b6',
        '#FB6964',
        '#342224',
        '#472E32',
        '#BDBB99',
        '#77B1A9',
        '#2c3e50'
      ];

   $(function (){
     var i = 0
     $('svg').find('path', this).attr('fill', 'bulbColors[i]')
     setInterval(function(){
       i++;
       if (i == bulbColors.length){
         i = 0;
       }
     $(this).fadeOut('slow', function () {
         $('svg').find('path', this).attr('fill', 'bulbColors[i]')
         $(this).fadeIn("slow");
       })
     }, 6000);
   })
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! So what's the question/problem exactly? I don't see an SVG anywhere. `var i` is dangerous for scoping problems. I recommend `let`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this code

```
$('svg').find('path', this).attr('fill', 'bulbColors[i]')
```

You need to unquote bulbColors[i], otherwise javascript reads the argument as a string, and not the hex color in the list at index [i].